# Bitcoin cash transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash

I have sent 0.05 Bitcoin Cash from my local wallet to Cex.io . what happened is that it also reducted my Bitcoin amount with -0.05 BTC. What can I do to get back my bitcoin amount?

I use Bitcoin Core- for BTC and Bitcoin ABC for BCH

Status of transaction in Bitcoin Core transaction is like this:
**Status: 4/unconfirmed**

[image]

Comment: can you provive more info? addressed, txid, screenshots? because replaying (duplicating) transactions in BTC/BCC networks **can not happen**

Comment: Transaction ID: 581694dcf694c55b51218b4b7850f13071038250761a53beaf47ed4e5f5f44d2

Comment: this id exists only in bcc-network, funds on your address in btc-network were not moved. something is wrong with your local wallet btc-software - it shows you incorrect info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin Cash transactions are Bitcoin Cash transactions while Bitcoin transactions are Bitcoin transactions, they're different. Your Bitcoin Core shows that transaction probably because Bitcoin ABC and Bitcoin Core uses the same datadir. Your 0.05 BTC is still there, it's just your confused Core client. All you need is to rescan Bitcoin Core (making Bitcoin Core reset its transaction history cache and re-searching for transactions). You can rescan as explained by BookLover's #9 reply on https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=171390.msg1820287#msg1820287 (Please use the shortcut once, or you'll rescan many times and waste time)

Next time, add `-datadir=C:\meh\BitcoinABCdir` to BitcoinABC's shortcut, as described by Booklover's reply, you just read. (Use this shortcut permanently)

Comment: rescan didn't helpped

Comment: and you are right my ABC and bitcoin core use same dir

Comment: Are you sure that you rescanned Core?

Comment: before starting ABC client I made a backup of bitcoin folder. now I tried to change the bitcoin directory for Bitcoin Core - and now everything is ok. Shows me correct balance.

Comment: I used this command "C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir=E:\Bitcoin